# mootools inject disabled element

Tags: dom, mootools, element, code-injection

I can't seem to figure out how to inject a disabled element. Any help will be appreciated.

I apologize, as I made several mistakes posting this. First of all, i was applying the attribute to an h3 element (how do you disable that??, you don't). Also, I'm afraid I have tried a : with still no effect. Please forgive my error, and here is the 'correct' incorrect code:

```
    //Score
    var span = new Element('span', {'class':'same_line'});
    span.inject(livegame_management);
        var label = new Element('label', {'class':'description', text:'Score'});
        label.inject(span);
        var score_input = new Element('input', {'size':'3', 'maxlength':'3', 'id':'team-'+i+'_score', 'disabled':'true'});
        score_input.inject(span);

        live_input.addEvents({
            change: function() {
                if (this.value > 0) li.fade('in');
                else li.fade(.5);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
var name = new Element('h3', {text:val, 'class':'drag-handle', 'disabled': true});
name.inject(li);
```